# exponent addition rule

Tags: abstract-algebra

The exponent rule says: $ n^a *n^b=n^{a+b}$ right?

But, exponents like $b^{\frac 12}$ have two answers,
or even more in the case of $b^{\frac 1{10}}$. So doesn't this
create a contradiction, for example according to the rule:

$$9^{\frac 12}*9^{\frac 12}=9^1=9$$

But, $9^{\frac 12}=3$ or $-3$
Implying:
$3*-3=-9$, which is not $9^1$

I hope this doesn't have some obvious explanation 
I'm missing, but how can the exponent addition rule be true then

Comment: You have to pick the same value for $9^{1/2}$ in each entry. You can't just choose the positive root for the first term and then change to the negative root for the second term. If you pick the positive root, then $-3=-(9^{1/2})$ which is consistent.

Comment: the basic exponentiation rule works for integers. If you want to extend it you can, but you have to choose branches for the exponential.  As you point out, if you try to make it hold for all the branches at once there will be contradictions.

Comment: For any complex numbers $n \ne 0$ and $a$ we define the multivalued function $n^a = \exp(a \log(n))$ using any branch of the logarithm.  **If** you use the same value of $\log(n)$ in each case, you do have $$n^a n^b = \exp(a \log(n)) \exp(b \log(n)) = \exp((a+b) \log(n)) = n^{a+b}$$  If you use different values of $\log(n)$, and $a$ and $b$ are not integers, your results may differ.

Answer (score 0):

When we restrict ourselves to the reals, we commonly use the convention that an $n$th root of a number $x$ refers to the positive $n$th root (whenever that is in doubt—e.g., when $n$ is even).  Thus, for instance, $\sqrt{x}$ conventionally refers to the positive square root, and if we wish to give it a different meaning, we usually have to specify it explicitly.

As long as we adhere to that convention, the rule you describe holds.  We say that $9^{1/2}$, the square root of $9$, is $3$ and not $-3$, and thus $9^{1/2}\times 9^{1/2} = 3 \times 3 = 9$.

When we expand from the reals to the complex numbers, however, that convention goes away.  A number such as $\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ has two square roots—$\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$—and there is no basis for identifying one of them as *the* square root.  One might occasionally prefer the root with the lowest argument (that is, the angle the value makes with the positive real axis in the complex plane), but that is not universally enough observed to assume without explicit mention.